# Python, Perl And C/C++ With GUI

Tags: c++, python, c, perl, integration

I'm now thinking, is it possible to integrate Python, Perl and C/C++ and also doing a GUI application with this very nice mix of languages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there is [Wx](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Wx/), [Inline::Python](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::Python) and  [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::C), but the question is **why?**

Comment: If that's the question, what's the answer? ;)

Comment: @DVK Especially when you don't know the question.

Answer (score 5):

Anything is "possible", but whether it is necessary or beneficial is debatable and highly depends on your requirements. Don't mix if you don't need to. Use the language that best fits the domain or target requirements.

I can't think of a scenario where one needs to mix Python and Perl as their domain is largely the same.

Using C/C++ can be beneficial in cases where you need hardcore system integration or specialized machine dependent services. Or when you need to extend Python or Perl itself (both are written in C/C++).

EDIT: if you want to do a GUI application, it is probably easier to choose a language that fits the OS you want your GUI to run in. I.e. something like (but not limited to) C# for Windows, Objective-C for iPhone or Mac, Qt + C++ for Linux etc.

Answer (score 3):

There's always [Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/).  Here's the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine).  It's a vm to allow you access your favorite libraries from different languages in one application.

Comment: I don't think it's a practical solution.

Comment: You shouldn't make a comment like that without an explanation.

Comment: Padre IDE allows writing plugins in any Parrot-supported language.

Comment: @manni And how do you know weather or not this is a project that needs to be production quality?

Comment: I don't, I don't make any assumptions. I just think we should provide good answers here. And as much as I'm looking forward to using Parot, currently, it's just not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible - but why add two and a half more levels of complexity?

Comment: Learn and practice all at the same time.

Comment: You can do that by doing one project in one and another in the other language. You'll learn much faster when you use a language in its best fitting domain.

Answer (score 1):

Python & Perl? together?

I can only think of an editor.